# C macro, something weird

Tags: c

Trying to figure out something simple in a C macro,
like this code for example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MACRO(b)  printf("%d\n", b*b)

int main()
{
    MACRO(4+1); 
}
```

The output for this code is 9, I think that it should be 25.
I don't have any idea why and how the result for this is 9 and not 25.

Comment: ^^^  the compiler does not care what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the macro, the preprocessor replaces it and its arguments verbatim, so the macro expansion in your code will look like

```
printf("%d\n", 4+1*4+1);
```

That will not provide you with the result you want, and it is one of the reasons that function-like macros are looked down upon.

You need to use parentheses to make sure this problem doesn't occur:

```
#define MACRO(b)  printf("%d\n", (b)*(b))
```

while will then result in the following expansion:

```
printf("%d\n", (4+1)*(4+1));
```

Whenever you have problems with something preprocessor related, there are options for just about all compilers to stop after the preprocessing stage, which allows you to look at the preprocessed source and which will help you with problems like this.

---

Also note that *another* possible problem here is if the expression you pass as argument to the macro is e.g. a function call with some side-effect that function will be called twice and the side-effect will be happen twice, even when using parentheses.

A simple example, using your macro:

```
int my_function(void)
{
    printf("Foo\n");
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    MACRO(my_function());
}
```

The above program will print `"Foo\n"` *twice*. If `MACRO` was a proper function the call to `my_function` would only happen once and the printout from the function would only happen once.

Comment: to prevent side efects, use: `#define MACRO(b)  do{int t=(b);printf("%d\n",t);}while(0)`

Comment: ..eh..should be `#define MACRO(b) do{int t=(b);printf("%d\n",t*t);}while(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Put parentheses around your macro to evaluate arguments in the correct order:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MACRO(b)  printf("%d\n", (b)*(b))

int main()
{
    MACRO(4+1); 
}
```